# Element of a Finite Galois Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

With $f(x)$ being an irreducible, separable polynomial of finite degree and $G/L$ the Galois extension of $f(x)$.  I know that $\exists x\in Gal(G/L)$ such that for all pairs of roots $(\alpha,\beta)$ there is a positive integer n such that $x^n(\alpha)=\beta$.

In terms of the symmetric group, if $\deg(f(x))=m$ then the cycle $(1~2~\dots~m-1~m)$ has to exist in the Galois group, where the Galois group can be represented by permutations of the roots of $f(x)$.  I just cannot remember why this is true.

It is not difficult to show that the Galois group has to have an element of order m, but unless the polynomial is of prime degree that doesn't help too much.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The Galois group need not contain an $m$-cycle. For example, if $m=4$, the Galois group could be the Klein 4-group. This will happen over the rationals if. e.g., $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson if that were the galois group, the f(x) referenced would be reducible.  It would actually be the product of 2 degree 2 polynomials.

Comment: The irreducible polynomial for $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ over the rationals has degree 4 and Galois group with no 4-cycle. Try it!

Comment: gotcha.  perhaps there was a stronger condition I'm forgetting then, maybe about there not being an intermediate galois field or something along those lines.  no matter. thanks for the help

Comment: You said "I know that $\exists x\in{\rm Gal}(G/L)$ such that for all pairs of roots $(\alpha,\beta)$ there is a positive integer $n$ such that $x^n\alpha=\beta$." This isn't true of all Galois extensions - I assumed you were setting this up as a hypothesis that we are supposed to take for granted. Rereading the question, I see that I read incorrectly, so I have deleted my comment and answer.